# Get IMG's source using JSOUP parser

Tags: android, jsoup

Using JSOUP I'd like to get link to for example photo from IMG tag. Sometimes ELEMENT doesn't have IMG tag inside HTML code. "Element link" has extracted HTML code from source downloaded code. To do this I've created method:

```
private String getPhotoForCover(Element link) throws NullPointerException
    {
        String photoLink = null;


        Log.i("IMG",link.getElementById("img").attr("src").toString());

// returning here "null" because I for now want to see extracted link in LOG.
        return photoLink;

    }
```

For example, HTML code from "Element link" is like following (shorted version):

```
<!-- <li> <a href="/pl/consignment/show/776609"><img src="/var/images/community_gallery/42017/595121/thumbnail.jpeg" class="thumbnail"></a> 
                                                                     </li> -->
```

After trying to get "src" content I get every time NULLPOINTER. How to properly get this "IMG" tag and it's "SRC" content?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to get an element by ID not by type. E.g. you are looking for an element with #img. I can check the documentation but I think this might be your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repalce `link.getElementById("img")` with `link.select("img")`

**Why?**

`getElementById("img")` looks for an element with the id "img", e.g. `<div id="img">`, this is not what you need. To find image elements you have to use `select("img")`

Also, you might want to get the absolute path instead of the relative path by using `attr("abs:src")` instead of `attr("src")`